# Necklace stones puzzle

Tags: code-golf, string

Given a necklace with color stones (yellow, white, brown, etc.) of at least two different colors, we describe that necklace using letters that correspond to each color, choosing an arbitrary starting point.

We try to answer these questions:

- How many distinct colors does the necklace have?
- What's the length of the longest segment of contiguous stones of the same color?
- If necklace can be cut at any position, removing all contiguous stones of the same color immediately to the left and to the right of the cutting point, what's the biggest amount of stones which could be taken?

Note that the necklace is considered cyclical. Therefore, letters at the start and end of the given input string can form a single sequence (see second test case below).

#### Test cases

```
aaaab -> 2 4 5
aabaa -> 2 4 5
uamaaauumaummuauamumummmmua -> 3 4 5
```

What's the shortest code to achieve this? Any language is welcome.

Comment: Why the arbitrary restriction to these programming languages?

Comment: I guess these are good options for *shortest code* approach

Comment: Out of the set of *all* programming languages, those are probably suboptimal. The questions on this site are actually contests and, unless there's a compelling reason to solve a task in a particular language, restrictions are generally frowned upon by the community.

Comment: Feel free to edit my question

Comment: I've reworded your question. If any part of my edit conflicts with your original intent, please undo it.

Comment: Is the necklace considered cyclical? For example, for `aabaa`, is the longest segment (question 2) 2 or 4?

Comment: Reto,  it's cyclical. It would be 4

Comment: Can we assume that there are stones of at least two different colors? If not, how should we interpret question 3?

Comment: Right, that's true,  at least  2 colors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 90 bytes

-2 bytes thanks to [Sʨɠɠan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/92689/s%ca%a8%c9%a0%c9%a0an)

```ruby
->a{[(a&a*=2).size,(c=a.slice_when{_1!=_2}.map &:size).max,c.each_cons(2).map(&:sum).max]}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72kqDSpcsEiN9ulpSVpuhY3o3TtEqujNRLVErVsjTT1ijOrUnU0km0T9YpzMpNT48szUvOq4w0VbeONavVyEwsU1KxASjSB7AqdZL3UxOSM-OT8vGINI5BQgQZQujQXLBtbC7VBt0DBLVqpNDE3MTGxtDQ3sTQ3tzQRyC0FwlwQW0kvOSOxqDhWryQ_PhGiacECCA0A)

Comment: `a.uniq` => `(a&a)`

Comment: You can save another byte abusing that to eliminate parens later: `->a{[(a&a*=2).size,(c=a.slice_when{_1!=_2}.map &:size).max,c.each_cons(2).map(&:sum).max]}`

Comment: @Sʨɠɠan Nice work. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

## CJam, 28 bytes

```
r__&,a\2*e`0f=_2ew::+]::e>S*
```

[Try it online.](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=r__%26%2Ca%5C2*e%600f%3D_2ew%3A%3A%2B%5D%3A%3Ae%3ES*&input=uamaaauumaummuauamumummmmua)

#### How it works

```
r    e# Read a whitespace-separated token from STDIN.
__   e# Push two copies.
&    e# Intersect two of the copies (removes duplicates).
,a   e# Calculate the length and wrap it in an array.
\    e# Swap the array with the input string.
2*   e# Repeat the input string two times.
e`   e# Perform run-length encoding.
0f=  e# Keep only the repetitions.
_2ew e# Copy and push the overlapping slices of length two.
::+  e# Add the integers in the resulting slices.
]    e# Wrap the entire stack in an array.
::e> e# Compute the maximum of each of the three arrays.
S*   e# Join, separating by spaces.
```

Comment: See the clarification I asked for under the question, after you posted your answer. This does not appear to treat the sequence as cyclical.

Comment: I think you might be able to accommodate that new requirement by simply repeating the input string. Add a `2*` after the initial `r`.

Comment: @RetoKoradi: Yes, that works. (Were busy editing the question.)

Comment: @Dennis I've edited questio removing a missconception on 3rd point.

Comment: Well, my initial version is 35 bytes. Not fundamentally very different, but your operator use for slicing and dicing the result of the RLE is more compact.

Comment: @diegoaguilar: Right, I misread that. Still, if there are at least two colors, the output will be the same.

Comment: Just asking, you repeat the input twice to simmulate the ciclycal necklace, right?

Comment: @diegoaguilar: That is correct. Again, this works only because there are at least two colors.

Comment: I don't even know which I should go for, both are great!

Comment: @diegoaguilar: Since you asked for the shortest possible code (code golf), the Pyth answer is superior to mine. I wouldn't accept an answer before at least a week has passed. Even if nobody is going to beat the Jakube's answer (which may or may not happen), it will give others a chance to participate.

Comment: I agree I would also love to see this in *not code golf languages* though

Comment: @diegoaguilar: Another good reason for not accepting an answer too soon. Most users answer in their favorite language, not the shortest possible one. Mine simply happens to be CJam.

Answer (score 7):

## Pyth, 20 bytes

```
l{zeSJhCr+zz8eS+VJtJ
```

Try it online: [Demonstration](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=l%7BzeSJhCr%2Bzz8eS%2BVJtJ&input=uamaaauumaummuauamumummmmua&debug=0)

#### Explanation

```
                      implicit: z = input string
 {z                   set of z
l                     len and print
         +zz          z + z (because cyclic)
        r   8         run-length-encoding
      hC              zip and only use the first column (quantities)
     J                store in J
    S                 sort
   e                  take the maximal element and print
               +V     vectorized add of 
                 JtJ  J and J[1:]
             eS       sort and print maximal element
```

Comment: See the clarification I asked for under the question, after you posted your answer. This does not appear to treat the sequence as cyclical.

Comment: @RetoKoradi Fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

## Haskell, <s>141</s> 137 bytes

```
import Data.List
l=length
m=maximum
v#w=l$v$group w
f n=(l$nub n,m$map l$group n,m[last#take i n+head#drop i n|i<-[1..l n-1]])
p n=f$n++n
```

Usage example:

```
*Main> map p ["aaaab","aabaa","uamaaauumaummuauamumummmmua"]
[(2,4,5),(2,4,5),(3,4,5)]
```

How it works: Like the other answers I deal with the cycle by working on the input string concatenated to itself.

- distinct colors: length of the list where duplicates are removed
- longest segment of the same color: group consecutive colors, get length of each group, take maximum
- split and take left and right segments: for each index `i`: split into left and right part at `i`, group consecutive colors in each part, add length of the last group of the left part and length of first group of the right part. Take maximum of the sums.

Answer (score 2):

### JavaScript (ES6), <s>203</s> 199 bytes

Credit goes to [this answer on Code Review SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/83718/21165) for the array unique function.

```js
f=w=>{for(x=Math.max,z=[],o=[[...w+=w].filter((x,p)=>w.search(x)==p).length],i=w.length-(c=1);i;)c=(w[i]!=w[--i]?(z.push(c)&0):c)+1;o.push(x.apply(0,z),x.apply(0,z.map((v,i)=>v+=z[i+1]|0)));return o}
```

#### Demo

ES6, so Firefox only for now.

```js
f = w => {
  for (x = Math.max, z = [], o = [
    [...w += w].filter((x, p) => w.search(x) == p).length
  ], i = w.length - (c = 1); i;)
    c = (w[i] != w[--i] ? (z.push(c) & 0) : c) + 1;

  o.push(x.apply(0, z), x.apply(0, z.map((v, i) => v += z[i + 1] | 0)));
  return o
}

// DEMO
console.log = x => document.body.innerHTML += x + "<br>";

console.log(f('aaaab'));
console.log(f('aabaa'));
console.log(f('uamaaauumaummuauamumummmmua'));
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-n`, 96 bytes

```perl
$_.=$_;@k{/./g}++;/(.)\1+(.)\2+/;say for 0+keys%k,length$&,(sort{$b-$a}map y///c,/((.)\2+)/g)[0]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JctLDsIgFEDRrTBAU8LnUZOOGhM34ArUNLRUNK1AgAlpunWxjWdwZ9ePYW5KwZ044669TAsIMCulLVSC3Gu690ShjSqjpwtI0mnM8TCxebQmvfCRVdGFtOCeY7V@lEcZAAYG1f8kYMhNPkpRm36j9bDT@ut8ejsbC782QtaycPsD)

Changed the output order:

```perl
Number of unique colors
Longest after cutting
Longest contiguous string of one color
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 124 bytes

```python
from itertools import*
I=input()*2
r=[len(list(g))for _,g in groupby(I)]
print len(set(I)),max(r),max(map(sum,zip(r,r[1:])))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JU5LCoMwEN3nFLNLIm5qdwUP4BlEymijDThJGDOgvbyNLW/xvouXjvyOoTmn@HLQgtb6nDkS@Ow4x7hu4ClFzpXqWh@SZGOrRnHbry6Y1W/ZLNbOkeFZL@ADLBwljYfp7KAS@5DhGm4ul8TWhLvhPxEmswnVH58M19zfHoO19iwHlHK7m@B6VN1PLUiIKEIoRILFSgFdWitdKhx/PCLqLw)